# Second derivative of Hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, summation, special-functions

I'm looking for the following second derivative

$$
\kappa_2 := \left  . \frac{d^2}{d\lambda^2} \ln \left({_2F_1}\!\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\,- \lambda;\,1;\,\alpha\right)\right) \right \vert_{\lambda = 0} , 
$$

where $\alpha$ is a real parameter in $[0,1]$. As you may have guessed I'm trying to compute the variance of a certain probability distribution.

The first moment is simple and is given by

$$
m_1 = 2 \ln \frac{1 + \sqrt{1-\alpha}}{2}.
$$

The second moment can be shown to be equal to the following

$$
m_2 = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\left [ \ln(1-\alpha y^2) \right ]^2}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} dy
$$

Mathematica can evaluate the above integral in terms of various function and polylogarithms (in fact dilogarithms). However the resulting expression is not even manifestly real. The above integral expression for $m_2$ is so far the best I found  to deal with but there are many others. In essence I am trying to find a "nice" expression for that integral ($m_2$).

I'd be happy if I'm given an expression which is manifestly real. I suspect that the combination $\kappa_2 = m_2 - (m_1)^2 $ (which is equal to the first equation) might look nicer and that some identity involving dilogarithms should be used.

*Added*

An alternative representation for $m_2$ (obtained using the series of the Hypergeometric) is the following

$$
m_{2}=2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1/2\\
n
\end{array}\right)\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}\left(-\alpha\right)^{n} \, , 
$$

where $H_n$ are the Harmonic numbers, i.e.

$$
H_n \, = \, \sum_{p=1}^n \frac{1}{p}
$$

So far this is the best I could get:

$$
\kappa_2 \,=\,  -4 \log ^2\left(\sqrt{1-\alpha }+1\right)+4 \log
   \left(4-4 \sqrt{1-\alpha }\right) \log
   \left(\sqrt{1-\alpha }+1\right)+4 i \pi  \log
   \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-\alpha }+1}\right)+4 \log
   (2) \log \left(\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)+4
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2 \left(\sqrt{1-\alpha
   }+1\right)}{\alpha }\right)-4
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{-\alpha +2 \sqrt{1-\alpha
   }+2}{\alpha }\right)
$$

I would like to avoid the explicitly imaginary (third) term which is compensated by the dilogarithm to produce a real result. Does anybody know an identity for dilogarithm that can be used here?

Comment: Can you include Mathematica's output? We might be able to make its reality manifest.

Comment: Can you post Mathematica's input ?

Comment: I am unable to get the analytical expression of $m_2$. Did you make a change of variable ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XnuHb.jpg) is the output.

Comment: @Lucian. Thank you very much ! It is not so complex na dnot ugly. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Lucian Thank you very much. Yes, that is essentially the expression I meant.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks, I would like to avoid the explicit imaginary terms (see added).

Comment: In such a case, what don't you generate a atble of values and properly interpolate ? I did this kind of things : not beautiful but efficient for computations.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm afraid my motivations are purely aesthetics. I would like a quantity which is real (and in fact positive being variance) to appear at least manifestly real. But your comment is making me wonder regarding the soundness of my motivations. Thanks for the interest anyway!

Comment: @Semiclassical Output added.

Comment: @lcv. If your motivations are purely aesthetics, keep this formula which is real valued at least for $a\leq 1$. Cheers.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the series the OP obtained can be written in the form $$2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(2n)! ~H_{n-1}}{n!^2 ~n} \frac{\alpha^n}{4^n}$$ which is perfectly real and converges very fast  (and has rational terms for rational $\alpha$).

Answer (score 3):

The definition of $\operatorname{Li}_2$ used in the last formula is
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z) =
-\operatorname{Li}_2 \left( \frac 1 z \right) -
\frac {3 \ln^2(-z) + \pi^2} 6,
\quad |z| > 1.$$
Therefore
$$\kappa_2 = 
4 \operatorname{Li}_2 \left( \frac \alpha {\omega - \alpha} \right) -
 4 \operatorname{Li}_2 \left( \frac \alpha \omega \right) +
 2\ln^2 \left( \frac \omega \alpha - 1 \right) -
 2\ln^2 \left( \frac \omega \alpha \right) + \\
 4 \ln \left( \frac \omega 2 \right)
  \ln \left( \frac {4 (4 - \omega - \alpha)} \alpha \right) -
 \ln(16) \ln(\alpha), \\
\omega = 2 + 2 \sqrt {1 - \alpha}.$$

Comment: Thank you.  I haven't checked your formula yet, but how did you remove the explicitly imaginary term?

Comment: The polylogarithm terms are real after the substitution, and $\ln^2 z = (\ln(-z) + i \pi)^2$ for negative $z$. The three imaginary terms cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

I will start from scratch. For any $R\geq 1$ we have
$$ (R-e^{i\theta})(R-e^{i\theta}) = (R^2+1)-2R\cos\theta \tag{1}$$
$$ 1-\frac{2R}{R^2+1}\cos\theta = \frac{R^2}{R^2+1}\left(1-\frac{e^{i\theta}}{R}\right)\left(1-\frac{e^{-i\theta}}{R}\right)\tag{2}$$
hence by setting $\frac{2R}{R^2+1}=\frac{1}{A}$ we have $A\geq 1$ and 
$$ \log\left(1-\frac{1}{A}\cos\theta\right) = \log\left(\frac{A+\sqrt{A^2-1}}{2A}\right)+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n R^n}.\tag{3} $$
By integrating both sides of $(3)$ on $(0,\pi/2)$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{x}{A}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(\frac{A+\sqrt{A^2-1}}{2A}\right)-2\operatorname{Im}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(iA-i\sqrt{A^2-1}\right)\tag{4} $$
and similarly
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x}{A}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(\frac{A-\sqrt{A^2-1}}{2A}\right)+2\operatorname{Im}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(iA+i\sqrt{A^2-1}\right)\tag{5} $$
such that by summing $(4)$ and $(5)$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{A^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx =\\= -\frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(2A\right)+2\operatorname{Im}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(iA+i\sqrt{A^2-1}\right)-2\operatorname{Im}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(iA-i\sqrt{A^2-1}\right).\tag{6} $$
Similarly we may integrate $\frac{\log\left(1\pm\frac{x}{A}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ on sub-intervals of $(0,1)$, always in terms of $\log$ and $\operatorname{Im}\operatorname{Li}_2$. Actually it turns out you do not need $\text{Im}\text{Li}_2$ to compute $\kappa_2$, just $\text{Li}_2$. From $H_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx$ it follows that the computation of 
$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\left[\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right]\frac{\alpha^n H_{n-1}}{n}$ boils down to the computation of

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left[\frac{1}{x}\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha x}}{2}\right)-\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha}}{2}\right)\right]\frac{dx}{1-x},$$
which by integration by parts and partial fraction decomposition reduces to the determination of the integrals over $(0,1)$ of
$$ \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{1-\alpha x}},\frac{\log(1-x)}{\sqrt{1-\alpha x}},\frac{\log(x)}{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha x}},\frac{\log(1-x)}{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha x}}.$$
The former two are equivalent to each other and elementary, the latter two depend on 
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)}{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha x}}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\,\phantom{}_4 F_3\left(\tfrac{1}{2},1,1,1;2,2,2;\alpha\right) $$
which reduces (up to elementary terms) to 
$$ \int_{\sqrt{1-\alpha}}^{1}\frac{x\log(1-x^2)}{1+x}\,dx $$
then to $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\alpha}}{2}\right)$. Some details needs to be filled but you have all the necessary ingredients.

Comment: Thank you, this seems a lot of work. I appreciate it, but I don't see how does that answer the question.

Comment: @lcv: it finds $\kappa_2$.